# How to set the PayPal-Request-Id using the PHP PayPal SDK?

Tags: php, paypal

Good day,

According to information from the PayPal site:
"When doing an execute or capture API call, set the PayPal-Request-Id HTTP header to something that will persist across retries that are not expected to result in new transactions - for example simply set this header to the PAYID or OrderId being acted on. This will give idempotent behavior."

In the script 'OrdersCaptureRequest.php' from the SDK there is a 'public function payPalRequestId($payPalRequestId)', but that function gets not called anywhere.

Unfortunately, I also cannot find any example how to call that function, also not from where to call it.

Does somebody have an example for me?
That would be very helpfull.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set the value with the function by...calling the function.

```php
$request = new OrdersCaptureRequest($orderId);
$request.payPalRequestId($myUniqueRequestId)'
```

Comment: thank you for your contribution; very helpful.